# Get PHP Contact Form to Work

Tags: php, contact-form

I am creating my first ever website. I have created a PHP Contact Form. Right now, my html and php files are stored locally, and I do not have a web host yet.

When the `Submit` button is clicked, the PHP file is downloaded, rather than the email message being sent. How can I get the Contact Form to send an email? Do I need a web host, first, before I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are loading your HTML files in a web browser and when they submit to the PHP page it loads the page. This is because you need a web server to actually process the PHP script.

- If you're running Windows you can look into [WAMPServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).
- There's also [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) for Macs.
- And [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) which works on Windows, Macs, and Linux.

There are lots of tutorials for using each f them so getting started should be easy to do.

Comment: John is 100% right, PHP is a server-side language. so you need a web server. I would recommend going with XMAPP, great for new devalopers. I believe if you type in "apache friends" in to Google it will bring you to their website.